# Wordpress footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

I'm new using Wordpress. I've installed Wordpress and everything is doing fine. Except for the footer of the page.

[image]

I assumed this was a code issue. I've tried to fix it, but no result.

footer.php:

```
    <div class="footer section large-padding bg-dark">

    <div class="footer-inner section-inner">

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-a' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="column column-1 left">

                <div class="widgets">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-a' ); ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?> <!-- /footer-a -->

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-b' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="column column-2 left">

                <div class="widgets">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-b' ); ?>

                </div> <!-- /widgets -->

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?> <!-- /footer-b -->

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-c' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="column column-3 left">

                <div class="widgets">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-c' ); ?>

                </div> <!-- /widgets -->

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?> <!-- /footer-c -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div> <!-- /footer-inner -->

</div> <!-- /footer -->

<div class="credits section bg-dark no-padding">

    <div class="credits-inner section-inner">

        <p class="credits-left">

            &copy; <?php echo date("Y") ?> <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>

        </p>

        <p class="credits-right">

            <span><?php printf( __( 'Theme by <a href="%s">Anders Noren</a>', 'hemingway'), 'http://www.andersnoren.se' ); ?></span> &mdash; <a title="<?php _e('To the top', 'hemingway'); ?>" class="tothetop"><?php _e('Up', 'hemingway' ); ?> &uarr;</a>

        </p>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div> <!-- /credits-inner -->

</div> <!-- /credits -->
```

Any idea?

Thx in advance

Comment: can you please post your footer.php file code

Comment: I already fixed it... It seems that the wordpress folder didn't had http://www.localhost:82/wordpress/wp-includes/css

I downloaded the wordpress zip again and fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is not in footer.php. If is it your home page then open the index.php file and at the end of the file check there is code like `get_sidebar();`. If you found the line like that then comment it out so may be the issue is fixed. Because i think it displays widgets sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

If you have changed your site or home adress; please check css file location and and set it as per in your html source